# Measuring RSSI of BLE Advertisement Packets Using Arduino

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi, hm-10

I am trying to find the RSSI of BLE Advertisements using an HM10 module and Arduino without actually connecting to the advertising BLE Device. The HM10 is in central role 
The `AT+DISC?` command only gives the address and the Bluetooth name.
`AT+RSSI?` gives no result
My firmware version is V540( obtained using `AT+VERS?`)

Can someone suggest me how RSSI of BLE Advertisement can be found? 
Is HM10  the right hardware to use for this purpose?
If not, what other module can i use?

Answer (score 0):

AT+DISC? command will return the Bluetooth Name and MAC Address.

AT+DISI? command will give the RSSI along with other information like MAC, UUID, and others.

AT+DISI? command is available in HM10 with firmware version v539 and above.